# programatically reading java keystore file jceks using openssl

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, aes, keystore

I am trying to do the AES encryption/decryption in java

I generated the secretkey using KeyGenerator. I stored the key using java keystore.

```
        Key myKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();

        KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam =
                new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("secretpass".toCharArray());

        //For writing the secret Key
        KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry skEntry =
                new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry((SecretKey)myKey);
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("test.ks");

        KeyStore ksout = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
        ksout.load(null,"changeit".toCharArray());
        ksout.setEntry("secretalias", skEntry, protParam);
```

I wanted to get this secretkey from this file using openssl programatically. Is it possible?  If so,  please give me some suggestions on how do I proceed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as the default keystore (jks) is a proprietary format used by Java.

To exchange the key you would need something portable like PKCS#11 (which is a supported `KeyStore` format at least in Java 8).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Is there any other way to do this ... I mean, any other standard way to achieve the exchange of key between java components and c++ components (which uses openssl).

Comment: @Gridahr He's just told you the answer to that. PKCS#11.

Comment: Where does it say that PKCS#11 is a supported keystore in Java 8? Not [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html).

Comment: @GregS [Look here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyStore).

Comment: @UwePlonus: Those are the reserved names, nothing more. It doesn't mean that Oracle has a provider implementation of it. And they don't.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm ...  I can not use the PKCS#11 now as it is not supported in Java7 .. Do I need have my custom keystorage implementation to share the key between java and c++ components ? (similar to .JCEKS format, I will just store the key in a file after encrypting it with pbewithmd5TripleDes).. Is it the right approach to solve my problem ?